# sed - Separate quotes and arguments

Tags: sed

So, I'm trying to get a script I'm working on to run another script in different directories with different arguments as defined in a text file.
Here's part of my code:

```
for bline in $(cat "$file"); do
  lindir=$()
  linarg=$()
  echo "dir: ${lindir}"
  echo "arg: ${linarg}"
done
```

Let's say I have a line in file that says this:

```
"./puppies" -c=1 -u=0 -b=1
```

How can I get an output of `./puppies` for `lindir` and an output of `-c=1 -u=0 -b=1` for `linarg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lindir="$( cut -d ' ' -f 1  <<<"$bline" )"
linarg="$( cut -d ' ' -f 2- <<<"$bline" )"
```

That is

```
while read -r bline; do
  lindir="$( cut -d ' ' -f 1  <<<"$bline" )"
  linarg="$( cut -d ' ' -f 2- <<<"$bline" )"

  printf "dir: %s\n" "$lindir"
  printf "arg: %s\n" "$linarg"
done <"$file"
```

If you're in a shell that doesn't understand "here-strings":

```
lindir="$( printf "%s" "$bline" | cut -d ' ' -f 1  )"
linarg="$( printf "%s" "$bline" | cut -d ' ' -f 2- )"
```